# React: Trigger a function when a child asynchronously updates its DOM after rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, nivo-react

Within `ParentComponent`, I render a **chart** (`ResponsiveLine`). I have a **function** (`calculateHeight`) calculating the height of some DOM elements of the chart.

To work fine, my function `calculateHeight` have to be triggered once the chart `ResponsiveLine` is rendered.

Here's my issue: useEffect will trigger before the child is done rendering, so I can't calculate the size of the DOM elements of the chart.

How to trigger my function `calculateHeight` once the chart `ResponsiveLine` is done rendering?

Here's a simplified code

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
    const myref = useRef(null);
    const [marginBottom, setMarginBottom] = useState(60);

    useEffect(() => {
        setMarginBottom(calculateHeight(myref));
    });
    
    
    return (
    <div ref={myref}>
        <ResponsiveLine marginBottom={marginBottom}/>
    </div>)
}
```

## **EDIT**

I can't edit the child `ResponsiveLine`, it's from a library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ResizeObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) API to track changes to the dimensions of the box of the div via its `ref` (specifically the height, which is the block size dimension for content which is in a language with a horizontal writing system like English). I won't go into the details of how the API works: you can read about it at the MDN link above.

The `ResponsiveLine` aspect of your question doesn't seem relevant except that it's a component you don't control and might change its state asynchronously. In the code snippet demonstration below, I've created a `Child` component that changes its height after 2 seconds to simulate the same idea.

[Code in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMAiB5AsnAMyghDgHIpUMBaAExIHo0AbYJAOxjIG4AoUSLDgBvWkgIoArs3goAzoiowANHElykAUQIEkGVeqTICBjQGUYKGElUwAnmCSL0MTcyQgOMAL6FipCiUeXl4GBjgATQhJOFpgWnYyeDkACwgAdzgYFOAFAkl2DGAIdlU5CDgASViSpLgAa3YMuHSUqzhgeHokOQA6UPCACSRKMgVyz2zgdgBzDvY4MGZ0JwgCDpgALl58wphihbQUZjRpKyRh4BmU+AAKJHdPTk24Nw8vAEoX9kkQACMRiJeHA4JQYJIoAsHu9OL0ZkgYAAhaLsOKzADCrC8yAwtw+vRSSCuNz43hCuyKJTg6JyzFocDxL2QLjeT3gwmBcDQJTk8AA2ry7O4ygiLEKkABdOAAXjU5ks1gAPMyML10WYzAAFYiOWBsOQAPluHJBIL+0DEUBeZAAjGAAB5wcqsel-ZiSJBkZSckGE4lbOAAVgADN6Qd4PnxOYZtLpcXiZQagaa4GFqW1Zk5sk4-dd4GssoSubT6dC2XAUARrFA4AAmJ16Eq0OQ+hswAAqoCQ0RgtwT0qTGhgYvct0F7kTDOEvRn45scFzNxeNpDEY+qlrSAAzJHOd5VHyJbvOWCIQtboq4gA3EQz3rCOfebwGmnAOmKhjXg27sk7AqUhZNRQShOAZL5nAwVkvGTLkeXgSh1llQxjEVQZ21wAAZTBgCvKDOCNH5mGYXcQW5dheTgPkQGAmZpmRGAYBIEUYFwGi6IgBiSClJD5XOW4ADZg2PEEYx0PRe37JMTVNYB1luABCBDelOKAQJgD5QQRM8oxTdx4GWXlEWYCA0HqMxgAALycWVgx000yIoiA-g0KAr0BWV2CQTJkDkSykGwZyRjcqB7k4KB9UnaSUwIaAGQc+AvCgOw4ALRL9Q0qKUw6OT5NCmAkt6c0oEtZF7XMqy4AAMkquBErsQqLRGUryqQXp3FmbI4CTISNLI-YfiQPgstNNMAAEYDkagkHtRwaBGYgoFbFN4so4Q3RMsy-O8bjarC+qipKiAyr8obhuyhl1tMlqZWlWUDKRYyrr83qSn6j1TuGodWKgWj2HoxiQFuI4TjOaxLjzPKCssH6EQ+EizvuoyNuu2VLs2qyPtNMkUwjOyQSclzgt6AmgqQW4lJUtTVDWo7rQOkZqHNe0yFx1tT0hMDJxJ1yRl6OI5DIzzcXh-dKKPOz2fPVtLxw28Z2EBCnwNJa4Blq8DUXANhGon72M4kBvAdD8vxVxVXzpVNlZTY2cKtuAfxCFbKBcBAIA4mUIKwPBlOd6xXY4256FONk4QRPCkTsSpaFuCg3a4D55N3Z2MH9mBehAy0LyAtTLd3IA)

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.18.5/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset('tsx', {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets['typescript'], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
// import {useEffect, useRef, useState, type ReactElement} from 'react';

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules instead of the above import statments
const {useEffect, useRef, useState} = React;

// You didn't show this function, so I don't know what it does.
// Here's something in place of it:
function calculateHeight (element: Element): number {
  return element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
}

function Child (): ReactElement {
  const [style, setStyle] = useState<React.CSSProperties>({
    border: '1px solid blue',
    height: 50,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // Change the height of the child element after 2 seconds
    setTimeout(() => setStyle(style => ({...style, height: 150})), 2e3);
  }, []);

  return (<div {...{style}}>Child</div>);
}

function Parent (): ReactElement {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [marginBottom, setMarginBottom] = useState(60);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref.current) return;

    let lastBlockSize = 0;

    const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
      for (const entry of entries) {
        if (!(entry.borderBoxSize && entry.borderBoxSize.length > 0)) continue;
        // @ts-expect-error
        const [{blockSize}] = entry.borderBoxSize;
        if (blockSize === lastBlockSize) continue;
        setMarginBottom(calculateHeight(entry.target));
        lastBlockSize = blockSize;
      }
    });

    observer.observe(ref.current, {box: 'border-box'});
    return () => observer.disconnect();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div {...{ref}}>
      <div>height: {marginBottom}px</div>
      <Child />
    </div>
  );
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!);
reactRoot.render(<Parent />);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you send a function to the child component that is called from the **useEffect** of the child component.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
const myref = useRef(null);
const [marginBottom, setMarginBottom] = useState(60);

someFunction = () => {
    setMarginBottom(calculateHeight(myref));
}


return (
<div ref={myref}>
    <ResponsiveLine func={someFunction} marginBottom={marginBottom}/>
</div>)
}

// CHILD COMPONENT

const ChildComponent = ({func, marginBotton}) => {
const [marginBottom, setMarginBottom] = useState(60);

useEffect(() => {
    func();
}, []);


return <div></div>

}
```

Comment: The issue is that I can't edit the child component. ResponsiveLine comes from a library

Answer (score 0):

You said,

> Here's my issue: useEffect will trigger before the child is done rendering, so I can't calculate the size of the DOM elements of the chart.

However, parent useEffect does not do that, It fires only after all the children are mounted and their useEffects are fired.

The value of `myref` is stored in `myref.current` So your useEffect should be

```
 useEffect(() => {
        setMarginBottom(calculateHeight(myref.current));
    });
```

Comment: That's what I expected me too, but it seems that it triggers useEffect before the whole DOM is rendered. I don't get access to all DOM element while if I trigger it later like with an "onClick", then it works like a charm

Comment: If the child component has an async op in its effect, then the parent effect might be fired before the async op completes.

Comment: That might def be the challenge here, do you know any workaround?